# javascript: cannot access object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

I need to get the username by using `Meteor.user()`. And it gives me the proper object with the username property which I cannot access.

My code:

```js
class Dashboard extends TrackerReact(Component){
    constructor(){
        super();
        //some code
    }
    
    render() {
        let user = Meteor.user();
        console.log(user);
        //cannot access user.username eventhough it is there
        return (
            //some code
        );
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: How are trying to access the username and what tells you that it is there?

Comment: @floverdevel I know it's there because i can console log that without any problem, but when accessing its property, there is problem and nothing gets rendered

Comment: What error are you seeing? It is entirely possible that the `render` code runs multiple times, in some of which it `user` is `undefined`.

Comment: What output do you have with console.log(user.username); ?

Comment: @MasterAM actually nothing shows, there is just blank page

Comment: @floverdevel, I've got none output, just blank page

Comment: and nothing in a console

Comment: Are you sure that the render function is called ?

Comment: @floverdevel, yeah it's called. But here even independent components are not showing

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the user object on state

```js
class Dashboard extends TrackerReact(Component){
    constructor(){
        super();
        state = {
          user: null,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
     this.setState({user: Meteor.user()}); 
    }
 
    
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.user);
        return (
            //some code
        );
    }
}
```